# Trying to install Ubuntu 20 on a PC without OS with USB stick. Laptop model ASUS VivoBook S15

Tags: system-installation, usb

When the installation is almost complete, the following error message is displayed:

```
the following file did not match its source copy on the CD
/target/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic79xx.ko
```

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Live CD verifies its integrity at boot. It is a good idea to let it finish to avoid such errors.

Comment: Ciao Kevin - the installation is from a USB pen drive. What do you suggest I should do to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check the integrity of the iso by comparing SHA256SUMS and allow the USB file system check before Try Ubuntu 20.04 to ensure that "no errors found".